# Why are there 3 TIE-fighters chasing an X-Wing in "Attack of the Clones"?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

Why are there 3 TIE-fighters chasing an X-Wing in "Attack of the Clones"?

[image]

Hat/Tip: "[Everything GREAT About Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of The Clones!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44H0MVjBDtM)"

**Only looking for in-universe answers.**

Comment: They were practicing for Death Star trench runs. Duh. :P

Answer (score 8):

This is what's known as an "[Easter Egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media))" and is referred to directly in the film's audio commentary with George Lucas and VFX Supervisor John Knoll. Basically they were having a little bit of fun by adding in something that harks back to the prior films. As with most Easter Eggs, we can reasonably assume that it's not meant to be taken seriously, especially since it contradicts what we know about the T-65 X-Wing's design pedigree from other canon sources. As such there is ***no*** in-universe explanation

> **JK:** *Coming up at the left of the frame there's a trench. In that trench is an X-Wing being pursued by three TIE-Fighters.
>   Right....here! Hard to see but it's there!* [chuckles]

Comment: Good find! But, the fact that it's an easter egg doesn't mean they didn't retcon it in-universe!

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - Now we need an in-universe reason for how (and why) Homer Simpson turned up in the next scene; http://www.eeggs.com/images/items/31.full.jpg

Comment: We also need a reason for why [R2-D2 was in Star Trek 2009](http://s3.media.squarespace.com/production/465215/5307116/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/R2D2-Star-Trek-1024x420.jpg).